# Next.js - GetStaticPaths TypeError

Tags: node.js, next.js

i have the following issue with getStaticPaths of Next.JS:

**TypeError: cias.map is not a function**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVZDp.png

Can someone help me with this, please?

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from '../../../styles/pages/container'
import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths } from 'next'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

    export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/infocadcias')
      const cias = await res.json()
    
      const paths = cias.map(cia => ({
        params: { id: cia.ID.toString() }
      }))
    
      return { paths, fallback: false }
    }
    
    export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/infocadcias/${params.id}`)
      const cia = await res.json()
    
      return cia
    }
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
    export default function InfoCia({ cia }) {
      return (
        <Container>
          <ul>
            {cia.map(p => (
              <li className="cia" key={p.ID}>
                <span>Name: {p.Name}</span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </Container>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I answered the wrong question below, but you should still take a look at that. you are getting that error because `cias` is not an array. Try logging that variable and update your question with the result if you still don't have a solution. It may be something like `{cias: [...]}` in which case you would need to change the map to `cias.cias.map(...)` OR destructure the variable on assignment `const { cias } = await res.json()`

---

In your `getStaticProps` function you are not returning in the proper format. You need to return an object with the `props` key like this:

```
{
  props: {
    cia: cia
  }
}
```

You can refer to the NextJS docs on getStaticProps here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

If that doesn't fix it, you should make sure that your `await res.json()` is returning an array.

Full example with update:

````js
import React from 'react'
import { Container } from '../../../styles/pages/container'
import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths } from 'next'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

    export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/infocadcias')
      const { cias } = await res.json()
       
      const paths = cias.map(cia => ({
        params: { id: cia.ID.toString() }
      }))
    
      return { paths, fallback: false }
    }
    
    export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/infocadcias/${params.id}`)
      const { cia } = await res.json()
    
      return {
        props: {
          cia: cia
        }
      }
    }
    
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
    export default function InfoCia({ cia }) {
      return (
        <Container>
          <ul>
            {cia.map(p => (
              <li className="cia" key={p.ID}>
                <span>Name: {p.Name}</span>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </Container>
      )
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Dylan, i did what you recommended, but don't work. Can you see my other question, pls? This comment space is to small to write the code. 

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63804077/how-can-i-print-a-list-of-objects-from-api-map-dont-reading-the-data]

Comment: I see, the fetch returns an object with the property `cias` which contains an array. change the map to `const paths = cias.cias.map(...)` I will update my answer to show that.

Comment: My answer has been updated. I went with destructuring on assignment `const { cias} = await res.json()` for a cleaner result. And FYI, rather than creating a new question, you can edit your current question.

Comment: Thanks, Dylan. I'm a newbie in programming :)