# How can i print a list of objects from API? .map don't reading the data

Tags: node.js, next.js

when i use the `.map` to print all companies in my page gives the following issue (TypeError cias.map is not a function):

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDeFl.png)

Code:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { Container } from '../../../styles/pages/container'
import React from 'react'
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import { Cias } from '../../../../model/cias'

export interface CiasProps {
  cias: Cias[]
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export default function CiasBrazil({ cias }: CiasProps) {
  return (
    <Container>
      {console.log(cias)}
      <ul>
        {cias.map(cia => {
          ;<li className="cia" key={cia.Code}>
            <Link
              href="/companies/brazil/[id]"
              as={`/companies/brazil/${cia.Code}`}
            >
              <a>
                <span>{cia.Name}</span>
              </a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        })}
      </ul>
    </Container>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/infocadcias')
  const cias = await res.json()
  return { props: { cias } }
}
```

Cias interface:

```
export interface Cias {
  Code: number
  Name: string
}
```

API:

[API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73jC8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is like

```js
{cias: []}
```

So to access cias,

```js
  const data = await res.json();
  const cias = data.cias;
  // ....
```